# How to get content from json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I am trying to build this script that gets viewer count and follower count from twitch. I got the viewer count one working but not the follower count. Here is the api/json link with the info I need. [Link](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_wildturtle/follows.json)

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var twitchName = "tsm_wildturtle";
  function showFollowers(b){
   alert(b._total);}
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+ twitchName +"/follows.json", function(b){document.getElementById("follows").innerHTML += b._total;}); 
  </script>
```

It displays nothing when I do this in the html: `Followers:<div id="follows"></div>`
Am I targeting the section wrong? Can someone please help. Yes I am using a current version of jquery for the `$.getJSON`

Comment: Your `{ }` do not look balanced. Check the `}` in the second last line.

Comment: Yes I see that but it doesn't change the outcome of the javascript.

Comment: Please update the question with the corrected parenthesis.

Comment: What error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: In the network console are you getting the status code 200 for the url 
"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_wildturtle/follows.json"?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_wildturtle/follows.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. This is what i am getting

Comment: [**Same-origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia definition "JSONP is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs running in web browsers to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same origin policy."

Here since its a cross domain request you could simply add the `'callback=?'` at the end

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_wildturtle/follows.json?callback=?", 
    function(data){
        //document.getElementById("follows").innerHTML += b._total;
        alert(data._total);
    });
```

See working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBuk5/)

Comment: this is the correct way but you helped a bunch. Thx! <script type='text/javascript'>
      function showFollows(data){
        alert(data._total);}
      $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_wildturtle/follows.json?callback=?", function(data){document.getElementById("follows").innerHTML += data._total;}); 
      </script>

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your browsers limitations are subject to Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Twitch does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and therefore you're not allowed to fetch the data from your browser.

However, you can use server side code to get the data that you want and send it back
.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get_twitch_user.php',
    data: {"twitchName" : twitchName},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Then at the server, in your get_twitch_user.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['twitchName'])):
    echo json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.$_GET['twitchName']));
endif;
```

This will absolve you of the issue you're experiencing in regards to CORS.